# using modal in gridview row editing C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

this is my bootstrap modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">
                            </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                            Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
```

i want to open the modal on button click,

the button is on my gridview item template,

my button look like this

```
<ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="btnedit" runat="server" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" CssClass="btn btn-warning" Width="100%"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and now i have created a protected void method on row editing,

which looks like this

```
protected void dgvEdit_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            dgvEdit.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            int index = e.NewEditIndex;
            LoadGridTask("EDIT", Session["CurrentUser"].ToString(), Session["TaskID"].ToString());

            Label taskinmodal = dgvEdit.Rows[index].FindControl("lblTaskName")as Label;
            Response.Write(taskinmodal.Text);

            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowPopup();", true);
            this.lblMessage.Text = taskinmodal.Text;
        }
```

the problem is when i add the code of my modal and set target id to my modal,

the code in `dgvEdit_RowEditing` not executing,

i want to add the value of my gridview row in my modal,

i think this is preventing my modal(`data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"` to executing `CommandName="Edit"`)

what i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use rowCommand instead of using 'dgvEdit_RowEditing'
     In your GridView add

```
 OnRowCommand="dgvEdit_RowCommand"
```

and change your method('dgvEdit_RowEditing') like this,

```
protected void dgvEdit_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.CommandName == "Edit")
   {
    dgvEdit.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        int index = e.NewEditIndex;
        LoadGridTask("EDIT", Session["CurrentUser"].ToString(), Session["TaskID"].ToString());

        Label taskinmodal = dgvEdit.Rows[index].FindControl("lblTaskName")as Label;
        Response.Write(taskinmodal.Text);

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowPopup();", true);
        this.lblMessage.Text = taskinmodal.Text;
    }
  }
```

Hope it works !!!

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out remove this **data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"** and let the **dgvEdit_RowCommand** to execute. On you dgvEdit_RowCommand method

```
protected void dgvEdit_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.CommandName == "Edit")
   {
    dgvEdit.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        int index = e.NewEditIndex;
        LoadGridTask("EDIT", Session["CurrentUser"].ToString(), Session["TaskID"].ToString());
    Label taskinmodal = dgvEdit.Rows[index].FindControl("lblTaskName")as Label;
    Response.Write(taskinmodal.Text);

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowPopup();", true);
    this.lblMessage.Text = taskinmodal.Text;
}
```

}

In the showpopup() function, please call

```
function ShowPopup(){
$("#myModal").modal();
}
```